# Is it possible to include selective [.js] files into specific generated [.html] pages using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

**Want to achieve**
I want to bundle my js files and dependencies using webpack and 'inject' specific files into specific generated html files. (This will not be an SPA)

My Webpack.config.js, looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
 entry: {
     vendor:"./js/SomeVendor.js",
     app: "./index.js",
     home: "./home.js"
        },
 output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
      filename: "[name]-[hash].bundle.js"
  },
 module: {
    rules: [
       . . . . .
         ]
 },
 plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(["dist"]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Custom template",
      template: "index.html"
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Custom template",
      filename: "home.html",
      template: "home.html"
   })
  ]
};
```

Now I want that my new-generated **'Home.html**' should only have *'home-hash.bundle.js' and 'vendor.bundle.js'* 
and similar for 'Index.html' [*'app-hash.bundle.js' and 'vendor.bundle.js'* ]

**Approach-1**

I sacrifice the 'hashing' of bundle names and donot 'inject' `.js` files into `.html`files. Instead, i manually include them in respective `.html` files with names as `app.bundle.js`, etc.

Any other approach ?

Comment: use chunks options on HtmlWebpackPlugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @PlayMa256
I accomplished it using the chunks options as you suggested. Posting here the answer for reference of others.

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: "custom1.html",
      chunks: ['custom1'],
      template: "app/components/custom1/index.html"
    }),
```